# sqlalchemy with sqlite to_sql not creating table nor database

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

Am new to sqlalchemy. When I run this code there is NO database. I want it to create the database, add the table defined and the data. Reading the documentation for to_sql this code should create the table if it doesn't exist ( it doesn't), when I run it it throws an error that the table has no column num 1 ??? AND does NOT create the database.  What am I doing wrong please?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

date_stuff = [ (20171219, 13.71,28),  (20171319, 144.71,33), (20171919, 99.99,99)]
labels       =  ['date', 'num 1' , 'num 2']

dev_env   = "/home/test/Desktop/mtest/hvdata/"
db_name = "tinydatabase.db"


def new_sql_add ( todays_data ):


        todays_data.to_sql(name='mcm_trends',  con = db ,if_exists='append')



if __name__  == '__main__' :

    db_path =  dev_env + db_name

    db = create_engine('sqlite:///db_path')

    df_for_sql  = pd.DataFrame.from_records( date_stuff , columns = labels)

    new_sql_add ( df_for_sql )
```

Comment: At least you're not passing the db path correctly. You're opening a file named *db_path* in the current directory instead of using the string bound to `db_path` as path.

Comment: @IljaEverilä  YOU ARE A GOD!!! I have spent hours looking at this and missed it completely. Thanks so much for helping out of a deep dark hole. I can't mark this as an answer as SE, correctly, doesn't trust my judgement.